# CodeIgniter "if not specific page" condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to hide few elements of my master template "home" for a specific page only.
The full URL looks like this: 
"sitesname.com/home/page/userpage".
Something like

```
<?php if ($this->router->fetch_class() != 'home' && $this->router->fetch_method() != 'page/userpage') : ?>
```

didn't work. Please help me settle the right condition.

Comment: Did you try to debug this by doing `var_dump($this->router->fetch_class(),  $this->router->fetch_method());`?

Comment: Yes, but it only tells me string(4) "home" and string(4) "page"

Comment: When your controller "page/user" load the view, send a var and just test that var in your view.

Comment: @DSDecay: That's because everything after `/page` is a *parameter* passed to the method.  Try using `$this->uri->segment()` instead.  See: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: new owners, new manual https://www.codeigniter.com/docs